# Object responds to selector but when I try send this selector - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

```
if ([timer respondsToSelector:@selector(userInfo)] ){
    [timer performSelector:@selector(userInfo)];
}
```

Timer is not nil and responds to selector. But I have EXC_BAD_ACCESS on 2 lines. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try using NSZombieEnabled. Your timer is probably pointing to portion of memory that has been released...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But [timer retainCount] == 3.. The object could be autoreleased when counter equal 3 ?

Comment: The objects can be autorelease even with retainCount==0. You are going to have problems with that tho... But with retainCount==3 it will be probably ok.

Comment: You should not rely on retainCount for ANYTHING.  It's contents are not reliable or predictable and should therefore not even be looked at.  Follow all of the memory management rules and you'll be fine.  Could you post more of your code, like where your timer is created and all lines that reference it?